# What is this unusual German army jacket?

Tags: military, identification, germany, uniform

I recently bought a military jacket and was wondering which part of the German army it belonged to. I couldn't find any information on the Internet, seems like this jacket is rare.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This jacket definitely belongs to the Bundeswehr, but has a very strange design.  It is made of moleskin and has traces of the Velcro panel being torn off from the pocket and flags from the sleeves, and has very strange metal buttons and clasp. Please help me to identify it.

UPD: The patch with the flag and the additional patch at the bottom from him were removed very neatly, barely visible (I tried to show them in the photo, but it is very difficult). On the second sleeve there are identical symmetrical marks from the patches.Same story with the Velcro panel and/or soldier's last name above the top pockets, the marks are barely visible.
[image]
[image]

There are also no traces of pairing old buttons and sewing on new ones; all threads are the same. The fastener on the collar is sewn on by the manufacturer, since there are no outlet holes on the inside of the collar, and it consists of two parts of fabric.
[image]

Comment: What makes you think it's Bundeswehr?

Comment: According to the state registries, Wispo was the name of a former clothing company in Germany. They were founded in 1976 in Regensburg, moved to Erkrath in 1999 and went bankrupt in 2007. It's stated purpose was the production and sale of clothing, especially for bad weather, industrial work and sports. I think it's reasonably that they would also produce uniforms or uniform-like clothing. I do not know if they ever supplied the Bundeswehr, perhaps someone else can use this information to find out more.

Comment: Can you add a view of the parts that were removed? Right now I see (or miss) a lot of details that would lead me to say it's just a jacket, all the parts giving it away as actually military surplus are missing. There never was any secret sauce, clothing companies manufactured to order for the army, but nothing kept them from making more and selling them to others. Especially in surplus stores, when sizes are asked for that aren't available as actual surplus, the companies will just produce more of them for those stores to sell.

Comment: A few "irregularities" that I would expect in a military jacket (and maybe they were removed or changed later): the buttons are not what a military uniform looks like. The shoulder parts to attach rank insignia are missing. Flags are missing, I cannot see actual spot where they are missing, maybe they just did a really good job to remove them without marks? The lower pockets on the front are weird, normal uniforms don't have them because you are supposed to tug it in if a shirt, or have your belt with stuff on it over them anyway if a jacket.